# Spring in Clocks

Tags: spring

Is the spring in a clock a torsion spring? As opposed to looking like a clothespin spring, its windings are all in the same plane, does it still work the same way?

Related Question: [Energy stored in a clothespin spring (non linear spring)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66426/)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably lots of different types of clock spring, but I'd guess you're thinking of something like this:

[image: Clock Spring]

This is not a torsion spring. The spring is basically a long strip of metal and the energy is stored by bending the strip of metal not twisting it. Like the example in your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66426/energy-stored-in-a-clothespin-spring-non-linear-spring), the reason for coiling the metal strip is to fit a long length of strip into a small space. You need a long length of strip so the deformation of the strip doesn't exceed the elastic limit.